# Testing server setup bash scripts

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04

I'm just learning to write bash scripts.

I'm writing a script to setup a new server.

How should I go about testing the script.

i.e. 
I use apt install for certain packages like apache, php etc. and then a couple of lines down there is an error.

I then need to fix the error and run it again but it will run all the install commands again.

The system will probably say the package is installed already, but what if there are commands which append strings to files. 
If these are run again it will append the same string to the file a second time.

What is the best approach to write bash-scripts like this?

Can you do test runs which rollback everything after an error or end of the script?

Or even better to have the script continue from the line where the error occured the next time it is run?

I'm doing this on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Answer (score 0):

it's a matter of how clear you want it to be to read it, but

```
[ -f .step01-done ] || your install command && touch .step01-done

[ -f .step02-done ] || your other install command && touch .step02-done
```

maybe a little easier to read:

```
if ! [ -f .step01-done ]; then
    if your install command ; then
        touch .step01-done
    fi
fi

if ! [ -f .step02-done ]; then
    if your other install command ; then
        touch .step02-done
    fi
fi
```

...or something in between.

Now, I would suggest creating a directory somewhere and maybe logging output from the commands to some file there (maybe tee it) but definitely putting all these files you are creating with touch there.  That way if you start it from another directory by accident, it won't matter.  You just need to make sure that apt-get or whatever you use actual returns false if it fails.  It should.

You could even make a function that does it in a nice way...

```
#!/bin/bash

function do_cmd() {
    if [ -f "$1.done" ]; then
        echo "$2: skipping already completed step"
        return 0
    fi
    echo -n "$2: "
    $3 1> "$1.out" 2> "$1.err"
    if $?; then
        echo "ok"
        touch "$1.done"
        return 0
    else
        echo "failed"
        echo -e "see \"$1.out\" and/or \"$1.err\" for details."
        return 1
        # could "exit 1" instead
    fi
}

[ -d /root/mysetup ] || mkdir /root/mysetup
if ! [ -d /root/mysetup ]; then
    echo "failed to find or create /root/mysetup directory
    exit 1
fi

cd /root/mysetup

# ---------------- your steps go here -------------------
do_cmd prog1 "installing prog1" "apt-get install prog1" || exit 1
do_cmd prog2 "installing prog2" "apt-get install prog2" || exit 1
do_cmd startfoo "starting foo service" "service foo start" || exit 1

echo "all setup functions finished."
```

You would use:

```
do_cmd identifier "description" "command or function"
```

description

```
identifier: unique identifier used when files are generated:  
    identifier.out: standard output from command  
    identifier.err: standard error from command  
    identifier.done: created when command is successful  

description: this is actually printed to the terminal when the step is being executed.

command or function: this is the actual command to run
```

not sure why stackoverflow forced me to format that last bit as code but w/e

Comment: Thank you however it seems to me putting all commands in double if-statements is not really an elegant solution to a common problem. It would be less work to just comment everything and test line by line. But there has to be some easy way to do this right?

Comment: see the last edit i made 27 mins ago.  You just have one function that you call repeatedly with every step.  If you need to group more complex operations together, you can create nice functions for them too and call them like **do_cmd "some_identifier" "description of what it does" "actual command or function to execute" || exit 1**

Comment: or just put the **exit 1** in the function like i commented and skip the **|| exit 1** after each do_cmd